# Using recordset in VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a huge data (16 files with 300,000 rows in each) in excel. I am trying to analyse the data via vba (For each file the recordset takes the data based on criteria). For 12 files it works, however when I increase the files involved the vba just dies, after opening and taking the information from 12th file.

```
connectionToDatabase.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
"Data Source=" & CStr(file) & ";" & _
"Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
connectionToDatabase.CursorLocation = adUseClient
recordsTable.Open "SELECT a, b,c,d ... z, where z>10000"
```

Comment: Is Cstr(file) the path and file name for all 12 excel files?  Are you closing each file when you are done with it?  Sounds like a memory problem.

Comment: It dies on the `.Open`?  It's not a specific file, but ANY file after the 12th?

Comment: [reference to potential memory leak issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/319998/bug-memory-leak-occurs-when-you-query-an-open-excel-worksheet-by-using-activex-data-objects-ado)

Comment: Yes, it dies on the open, because of any file after 12th

Comment: it goes through for loop, Cstr(file) refers to each file in specific folder

Comment: Do you do any housekeeping inbetween, like closing recordset and connection.  It could be what happens after using the recordset, what happens in the code after

Comment: After taking the results and calculating I use the folloowing code- recordsTable.Close
connectionToDatabase.Close
Set recordsTable = Nothing
Set connectionToDatabase = Nothing

Comment: Perhaps a redesign is needed. Why not store all the data in MS Access or a MS SQL Server database (you can use SQL Server Express for Free)?

Comment: I can't do that, it will exceed the Access 2GB capacity, I can't install SQL Server on this computer. Moreover, the calculations I do can't be done in that environment it is a lot easier in excel

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?  For the potential redesign, you can use an Access table that gets linked to each spreadsheet as you loop through.  [here's an example to work with](https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/211907-link-tables-code)  Excel 5.0 may not work, as that's old, you can use Excel 11 if you have it installed